# I'm trying get the image from URL (ImageGetter)

Tags: android, textview, android-image, androidhttpclient

I have a external SQLite Database in TXT. The entries should have text and images from URL, so, I implementend ImageGetter in my Project. But when I put the img src tag in the entry like: `< img src="https://www.backpacker.com.br/img/midia_site/uol.jpg">` (I added a space afer < on purpose)  the application is forced to close.

This is my code:

URLWorldActivity

```
public class URLWordActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.word);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        finish();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        TextView word = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word);
        TextView definition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.definition);

        int wIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD);
        int dIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION);

        word.setText(Html.fromHtml(cursor.getString(wIndex)));

        URLImageParser p = new URLImageParser(definition, this);
        Spanned htmlSpan = Html.fromHtml(cursor.getString(dIndex), p, null);
        definition.setText(htmlSpan);

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));     
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);


    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:
            onSearchRequested();
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, BancoDictionary.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}



              public class URLImageParser implements ImageGetter {
            Context c;
            View container;

            /***
             * Construct the URLImageParser which will execute AsyncTask and refresh the container
             * @param t
             * @param c
             */
            public URLImageParser(View t, Context c) {
                this.c = c;
                this.container = t;
            }

            public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                URLDrawable urlDrawable = new URLDrawable();

                // get the actual source
                ImageGetterAsyncTask asyncTask = 
                    new ImageGetterAsyncTask( urlDrawable);

                asyncTask.execute(source);

                // return reference to URLDrawable where I will change with actual image from
                // the src tag
                return urlDrawable;
            }

            public class ImageGetterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable>  {
                URLDrawable urlDrawable;

                public ImageGetterAsyncTask(URLDrawable d) {
                    this.urlDrawable = d;
                }

                @Override
                protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
                    String source = params[0];
                    return fetchDrawable(source);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
                    // set the correct bound according to the result from HTTP call
                    urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + result.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0 
                            + result.getIntrinsicHeight()); 

                    // change the reference of the current drawable to the result
                    // from the HTTP call
                    urlDrawable.drawable = result;

                    // redraw the image by invalidating the container
                    URLImageParser.this.container.invalidate();
                }

                /***
                 * Get the Drawable from URL
                 * @param urlString
                 * @return
                 */
                public Drawable fetchDrawable(String urlString) {
                    try {
                        InputStream is = fetch(urlString);
                        Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
                        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0 
                                + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()); 
                        return drawable;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        return null;
                    } 
                }

                private InputStream fetch(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString);
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
                    return response.getEntity().getContent();
                }
            }
        }  
    }
```

URLDrawable

```
public class URLDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
// the drawable that you need to set, you could set the initial drawing
// with the loading image if you need to
protected Drawable drawable;

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    // override the draw to facilitate refresh function later
    if(drawable != null) {
        drawable.draw(canvas);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can add the error log, to see where the fail comes.

Comment: Do you really need to use it in a Bitmap ? Do you intent just to show the image or manipulate it?

Comment: @wviana Just to show the image! I don't want to manipulate it!

Comment: Nowadays you don't need to write tons of code to make such things work without bugs. Better solution is to use existing libs, there are two main players in the game: Picasso and Glide

Comment: @ViktorYakunin Where do I get this one?

Comment: @FotogênicasBrasil http://square.github.io/picasso/ and https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 0):

As you told me that you just want to show the image. I suggest you to use a image loading library as [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). It would make load a image from a URL as easy as `Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);` and you won't even need no care about using UIThread.

Comment: I have many data in my database and each item should show a differen http image. How can I do this?

Comment: @FotogênicasBrasil Are you showing it in a `ListView` or something like this ? Probably you'r using an adapter. Inside your view adapter you could set the image using Picasso.

Comment: I'm showing it in a `TextView`. I have a external database (in txt file) that contains 2 columns (key_word and key_definition) like this: piece of cake // <img src="image.jpg"> bla bla bla spill the beans // <img src="image2.jpg"> bla bla bla . So, I want to Picasso show the specific image in a textview what I put in my data position. I am a newbie. If you want, I'll add my classes activities above.

Comment: @FotogênicasBrasil You'r soppose to use TextView just for text. If you need to show images with text, you could create compose layouts, something like a `<LinearLayout><ImageView/><TextView/></LinearLayout>`